# C# Serialize Propery of two different Types to JSON

Tags: c#, json, class, properties

I need to either get the Property Type to be a string or the Class TypeClass based on user Input, so that i can Serialize it to a json.

So I want to either get this

```
{"query":"type":"Gold Ring","sort":{"price":"asc"}}
```

or this json

```
{"query":"type":{"option":"Gold Ring","cat":"Jewelery"},"sort":{"price":"asc"}}
```

But I don't really know how to achieve that.

```
[JsonProperty("type", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public string Type { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("type", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public TypeClass TypeMap { get; set; }
```

Type Class :

```
public partial class TypeClass
{
    [JsonProperty("option", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Option { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cat", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Cat { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I parse json either into a string or another concrete type as object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33080843/10263)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet (I haven't tested this yet so there's a good chance I may be wrong here) would be to test for the value that's retrieved by the parser, and have that be  and then do stuff with it. So for example you could do

```
JObject json = (JObject)JToken.Parse({JSON FILE NAME});
```

And then do something like this:

```
if(json["query"]["type"].Type == JTokenType.String)
{
    //Do stuff if if you just type a string as a straight up single string 
}
else
{
    //Do stuff you would do if it were a TypeClass value inside of the json
}
```

What you could also do is just do something more along the lines of this:

```
var json = (JObject)JToken.Parse({JSON FILE NAME});

if(json["query"]["type"].Value().GetType() == typeof(string))
{
     string json = json["query"]["type"];
     //Do string stuff
}
else if (json["query"]["type"].GetType == typeof(TypeClass))
{

 TypeClass json = new TypeClass() { 
     Option = json["query"]["type"]["option"], 
     Cat = json["query"]["type"]["cat"],};

 //Do TypeClass stuff

 }
```

Or maybe even something with Templates:

```
//Method declaration 
static bool IsTypeClass<T>(T value)
{
   Type ParamType = typeof(T);

    if(T.GetType() == "TypeClass")
    {
        //Is a TypeClass object
        return true;
    }
    //Is not a TypeClass Object
    return false;
}
```

And then use that wherever you need to compare if the type is an string or a TypeClass.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your response but i need to Serialize the Class to GET the json. It is sent to a server.
I read my Question again and i think i misspelled my question, sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Put your JSON example in input of this site http://json2csharp.com/

```
{"query":{"type":"Gold Ring"},"sort":{"price":"asc"}}

public class Query
{
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Sort
{
    public string price { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Query query { get; set; }
    public Sort sort { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that your examples of json are not correct,,   verify there https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Yeah that might be because i cropped it.