# Deserialize json, same property name but different type

Tags: c#, json

I'm receiving a json file that I need to process, it has a set of questions and answers.  The answers have different dataTypes and therefore have different value properties. How do I deserialize using newtonsoft to different "Value" classes. This is obviously failing because values not always a `List<string>`.

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(filePath))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    var jsonClass = (jsonClass)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(jsonClass));
}

public class jsonClass
{
    public ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }   
}

public class Answer
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

```
{
    "answers": [
        {
            "label": "Name",
            "dataType": "FreeText",
            "values": []
        },
        {
            "label": "Photo",
            "dataType": "Image",
            "values": []
        },
        {
            "label": "Done",
            "dataType": "FreeText",
            "values": [
                "Yes"
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Time",
            "dataType": "FreeText",
            "controlType": "Dropdown",
            "values": [
                "30 mins"
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "AdditionalPhotos",
            "dataType": "Image",
            "values": [
                {
                    "identifier": "f4755036-a4f4-4968-88aa-0bd9c71f06cf",
                    "filename": "1.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "identifier": "98d7d72d-2939-49f6-acc7-ac091fde5480",
                    "filename": "2.jpg"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is the deserializer? Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C#: Deserializing JSON when one field can be different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922848/c-deserializing-json-when-one-field-can-be-different-types)

Comment: I'm using Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: This is IMHO misuse of JSON, since you will lose C# type safety when using something like `List<object>` or `List<dynamic>`.

Comment: Try `List<JToken>`.